# Redirecting old PHP links to Django urls

Tags: django, redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I am getting a lot of search engine referral links for my previous PHP developed site that has now been migrated over to Django.  I made a url redirect for the  old php links like `search.php?name=john+smith` to the same view for my django search url as shown here:

## urls.py

```
url(r'^search.php/$', profile_search, name='search'),
url(r'^search/$', profile_search, name='search'),
```

Will Google eventually update those old links if I redirect through urls.py or do I need to make a 301 redirect? If so how would I do this with django and nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this at nginx level - this is much more efficient than having Django handle it. Assuming the Django view expects the same query arguments, you can do this in your nginx `server` block:

```
location = /search.php { 
    return 301 http://$server_name/search/$is_args$args; 
}
```

This will redirect all requests for `search.php` to `/search/`, preserving any query arguments.

A 301 response is definitely the correct approach - you don't want to serve duplicate content on different URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have HttpResponseRedirect in your `profile_search` method, you don't actually have any sort of redirect here at. But what you really want to use is [HttpResponsePermanentRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect)

```
def profile_search(request):
     return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/somether/url/?based_on_request_params')
```